# React useState no changing value in render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with customButton for PWA:

```
const PWA = () => {
  const [supportsPWA, setSupportsPWA] = useState(false)
  const [deferredPrompt, setDeferredPrompt] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setDeferredPrompt(e)
      setSupportsPWA(true)
    }
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handler)

    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handler)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {supportsPWA.toString()}
      {console.log(supportsPWA)}
      {supportsPWA && <div>test</div>}
    </>
  )
}
export default PWA
```

I have `beforeinstallprompt` which I change `supportsPWA` status from `false` to `true`. In render I have `supportsPWA.toString()` it's always `false`. Console log return me: `false` and next `true`, so if `supportsPWA` is `true` why React not render `div test`?

***EDIT:***

I found where is the problem. I render PWA component in another component: `{showMobileMenu && (<PWA />)}`. `showMobileMenu` I changing by button (from `false` to `true` ) and here is problem. When I remove `showMobileMenu && ...` and I have only `<PWA />` then div test is rendering correctly. But I dont know how I can resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540985/react-usestate-doesnt-update-in-window-events

Comment: You sure this component is not dismounted and mounted again? How many entries do you have in the console for `{console.log(supportsPWA)}`? Just 2, false and true? Or more?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I have only false and true

Comment: That's weird. I'd add more logs (before add/remove event listener and inside the handler), maybe that can bring some light?

Answer (score 1):

Well in your case instead of doing `{showMobileMenu && (<PWA />)}` which dismounts and mounts your component every time just show/hide content in your PWA component, if that is acceptable:

```js
const PWA = ({ showPWAComponent }) => {
  const [supportsPWA, setSupportsPWA] = useState(false)
  const [deferredPrompt, setDeferredPrompt] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setDeferredPrompt(e)
      setSupportsPWA(true)
    }
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handler)

    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handler)
  }, [])

  return showPWAComponent && (
    <div>
      {supportsPWA.toString()}
      {console.log(supportsPWA)}
      {supportsPWA && <div>test</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
export default PWA
```

And in the other component where you use PWA go:

```
{<PWA showPWAComponent={showMobileMenu} />)}
```

In any other case this case that you have will not work exactly because you have that removal of component there.

Comment: Np, i edited my answer also, but there is not much to do actually for your case. If this is the answer you were looking for