# React.js State not updating in Event Listener in useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

So, What I'm trying to do is add an event listener to a button that when pressed takes the value of a state and console log it. But the logged value never updates even after the multiple setState calls.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      const seamCarve = document.getElementById("process");
    
      seamCarve.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        console.log(seamValue);
      });
    }, []);
```

And then there's the button that triggers it

```html
          <div id="seamvalue">
            <Typography variant="h6" align="center">
              Seams Reduction:<span id="valueOfSeam"> {seamValue} </span>
            </Typography>
          </div>
    
          <Button
            id="leftslider"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() =>
              seamValue - 10 > 0 ? setSeamValue(seamValue - 10) : setSeamValue(0)
            }
          >
            <Typography>{"<"}</Typography>
          </Button>
    
          <Button
            id="rightslider"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => setSeamValue(seamValue + 10)}
          >
            <Typography>{">"}</Typography>
          </Button>
    
          <Button id="process" variant="contained" color="primary">
            <Typography>Carve</Typography>
          </Button>
```

The value changes as I click on the sliders but when I press the Button with id="process" with an event listener associated with it, it only prints 20 even after updating the state.

Answer (score 27):

Don't use native DOM methods like `addEventListener` in React if at all possible - instead, work *within* React to achieve the same effect. It'll make a whole lot more sense and will require less convoluted code.

Put the click listener in the JSX syntax returned instead.

```
<Button
    id="process"
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    onClick={() => console.log(seamValue)}
>
    <Typography>Carve</Typography>
</Button>
```

If you absolutely cannot attach the click listener via React for some reason, then attach the listener again when the state changes. Also note that in order to start a function, you need a `{` after the `=>`, unless you're using concise return (which you aren't here).

```
useEffect(() => {
    const seamCarve = document.getElementById("process");
    const handler = () => {
        console.log(seamValue);
    };
    seamCarve.addEventListener('click', handler);
    return () => seamCarve.removeEventListener('click', handler);
}, [seamValue]);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice OP was using the "onClick" event listener. Then my answer just applies to the general use of `document.addEventListener`.

Comment: The problem i have is that i need access to certain elements that I can't get access if I use that.

Comment: @Akash Why can't you access it? If the state(s) you need isn't in the component where you click on the button, put the state in a parent component instead and pass it down.

Comment: I used a very non reactive way to add a bunch of event listeners because I'm primarily working with HTML Canvas and I need more flexibility than the wrappers provide. The useEffect hook with no dependencies adds event listener that load the image and then draw the loaded image on canvas.

Answer (score 8):

State variables don't update itself inside an EventListener. If you want to update and access some state inside an EventListener, look into `useRef`. Also, you need to replace your 2nd `useState` statement with `useEffect` since that's what you wanted to implement. A relevant post that should answer your question: [Wrong React hooks behaviour with event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845595/wrong-react-hooks-behaviour-with-event-listener)

EDIT: as @CertainPerformance stated, event listeners like `onClick` can be directly used inside the jsx. My answer applies to the use of event listeners on the `document`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was looking for a solution to use the `selectionchange` event and set the `state` accordingly. I found out you can pass the `state` and `setState` function via args to another function and it works perfectly

```
  const [selectedText, setSelectedText] = useState('')

  function handleStateChange(func, value) {
    if (func) {
      func(value)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleSelectionChange = () => {
      const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
      handleStateChange(setSelectedText, selectedText)
    }

    document.addEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelectionChange)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('selectionchange', handleSelectionChange)
    }
  }, [])
```