How can I get new state in function in React
First version as below
 const TestApp = () => {
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);

    const incrementSpeed = () => {
      console.log(speed, `speed`); // Always console 1, how can I get new state?
      setSpeed(speed + 1);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'z') {
          incrementSpeed();
        }
      });
    }, []);
    return <></>;
  };

  export default TestApp;

I see all answers, help me a lot. But it can not fix my problem. Therefore I edit this question again.
Second version as below
const TestApp = () => {
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);

  // a state updated in oanother function, but below function can not get new state
  const incrementSpeed = () => {
    console.log(speed, `speed`); // Always console 1, how can I get new state?
    window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'o') {
        setSpeed((speed) => speed + 1);
      } else if (e.key === 'p') {
        incrementSpeed();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handle);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handle);
  }, [speed]);
  return <></>;
};

export default TestApp;


There are 2 actions.

add speed + 1
call incrementSpeed

This 2 actions implements by window.addEventListener, but this is not point. You can also get this by 2 buttons. The point is incrementSpeed only trigger one time. But setSpeed trigger many times. I understand why incrementSpeed always get old state. But I don't know how to fix this.

Thrid version 
Above code is just a simple version. I will try to explain why I do this. I am developing a browser extention. It has 2 functions.

Scroll automatically
Adjust scroll speed
So, a function called autoRead code like below

  const autoRead = () => {
    if (stopAutoReading.current) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(autoRead);
      return;
    }
    recordScroll.current += config.speed / 100;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = recordScroll.current;
    if (enableAutoReading.current) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(autoRead);
    }
  };

The autoRead execute when user press x, when user press arrow left or right can ajust read speed. The enableAutoReading is a ref control whether autoRead execute

Please do not edit the question like that. This makes all answers invalid. Instead, add both code snippets so that proper history can be maintained

Also, I got a problem is not helpful to other users right. Please mention the problem so future readers can benefit from this question by understanding the context.

thx, I have post all code version and describe

BTW: So you want an infinite loop in incrementSpeed? Because it calls itself using requestAnimationFrame. Or do you want it to stop?

Thanks for updating. This can be done using refs, I can update my answer to help you but I do not understand what is happening here. incrementSpeed will be called forever right. Should we stop it at some point?

In my true bussinuess. There has a variable whit useRef named continueAction, the incrementSpeed  well judge if continueAction is true. If true, call requestAnimationFrame

Does this help you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rxd31t?file=src%2Fmain.jsx,src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev. I am not sure why you are logging the value of speed inside incrementSpeed. It can be done outside also. Do you not require the updated speed value in the JSX but inside the function itself?

You can see the the bottom part of question. The speed from config. this is a state. So I need to change state to ref?

You can see the the bottom part of question. I read ur code. But the quesition is the true speed is part of config. the config updated in other component . So I make it as a state.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If I'm not mistaken, what you're looking for is a way to properly increment the value. Here's how I would go about it.
React state updates especially on functions with hooks are going to be batched, so whenever you console.log in your code, you will see the current value of variable speed. It is expected as it hasn't run through the full cycle of re-render/state update.
To ensure that increment is done properly based on what the current value is, you can pass a function into the setter function that does exactly that.
Your incrementSpeed function would look like below:
const incrementSpeed = () => {
  console.log(speed, `speed`);
  setSpeed(currentSpeed => currentSpeed + 1); // Note that we passed the function here, as it can also accept this kind of function which accepts the current state as argument, we could use it immediately like so.
  window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
};

You may also log it inside that function like below, but I'm not sure why you would want that in the current context but here it is:
setSpeed(currentSpeed => {
  console.log('previous speed', currentSpeed);
 return currentSpeed + 1
});

Edit: It is expected that you will not be able to get the updated value of the state inside the incrementSpeed function as by the point it is logged it is still on the previous value. For your use case we can make use of useRef:
Instead of useState replace it with useRef like so:
const TestApp = () => {
  const speedRef = useRef(1);// const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);

  // a state updated in oanother function, but below function can not get new state
  const incrementSpeed = () => {
    console.log(speedRef.current, `speed`); // Should now be able to see latest value as long as flow of the code is logically correct
    window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'o') {
        speedRef.current = speedRef.current + 1 // setSpeed((speed) => speed + 1);
      } else if (e.key === 'p') {
        incrementSpeed();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handle);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handle);
  }, []);
  return <></>;
};

export default TestApp;

With regards to your 3rd version, you can also just use a ref for it there I believe.
  const autoRead = () => {
    if (stopAutoReading.current) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(autoRead);
      return;
    }
    recordScroll.current += config.speedRef.current / 100;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = recordScroll.current;
    if (enableAutoReading.current) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(autoRead);
    }
  };


Oh you also have to make sure that your window.listener useEffect is only run once per re-render, so making the dependency array empty is what I can advice. Since we're now using ref it wouldn't really be something that useEffect cares about

I have updated my question. Can you see again and update answer? Thx

@Eve-Sama I got it. At the current state of you code, what you're looking to use is not useState but useRef, I've updated the code above to show.

speed is a closed in variable. Think closures. The value of speed was closed over by incrementSpeed. It is logging and using the same value.
See, the incrementSpeed which is created afresh with the new state value is not the one passed into requestAnimationFrame. requestAnimationFrame is still using only one version of incrementSpeed which has the value of speed as 1.
With hooks based React, the best place to see updated state values is inside the render body itself. There you can see the updated values.
So move console.log at the same level as incrementSpeed.
But the problem that the speed reference is closed over still exists. So you will have to use the updater function pattern of setState. This guarantees that you get the previous state value correctly and is the recommended way.
const App = () => {
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);

  const incrementSpeed = () => {
    setSpeed(speed=> speed + 1);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'z') {
        incrementSpeed();
      }
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(speed, `speed`); 

  return <></>;
};

Demo
NOTE: While console.log inside the setter can be done to check the value, it is not recommended as it is a side effect.

I have updated my question. Can you see again and update answer? Thx

In React Functional components when you update the state you can't get the latest values of State in function. when you call the function next time you will get the last updated value.
For example:
keydown 1st time:
log: 1 speed
speed value of state after update: 2
keydown 2nd time:
log: 2 speed
speed value of state after update: 3
To get the latest value in console log:
const TestApp = () => {
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);

    const incrementSpeed = () => {
      s = speed +1
      console.log(s, `speed`); // Always console 1, how can I get new state?
      setSpeed(s);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'z') {
          incrementSpeed();
        }
      });
    }, []);
    return <></>;
  };

  export default TestApp;

Or like this:
const incrementSpeed = () => {
    // Use a functional update to ensure you're always working with the latest state
    setSpeed(currentSpeed => {
      const newSpeed = currentSpeed + 1;
      console.log(newSpeed, `speed`); // This will log the updated speed
      return newSpeed;
    });
    window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
  };


As per this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67244182/11976596

State variables don't update itself inside an EventListener. If you want to update and access some state inside an EventListener, look into useRef. Also, you need to replace your 2nd useState statement with useEffect since that's what you wanted to implement.

A better approach would be to pass updated state as parameter as below
 const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);

  const incrementSpeed = (speed) => {
    console.log(speed, `speed`); // Always console 1, how can I get new state?
    setSpeed(speed + 1);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(incrementSpeed);
  };

  const keydownEvent = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'z') {
      incrementSpeed(speed);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown',keydownEvent);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown',keydownEvent);
    }
  }, []);
  return <>{speed}</>;

